# Single homed, dual homed and double sided vpc

Tags: vpc

I'm trying to figure out scenarios in which one would use single homed, dual homed and double sided vpc and what benefits each topology would have?

I can already see that dual homed vpc would have better redundancy and more bandwidth than single homed. What other advantages and disadvantages exist between each method?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

You kind of answered it yourself.  The advantage for each is an increased level of redundancy.  The advantage of vPC is that is provides link redundancy as well as chassis redundancy.  A dual-homed connection would be used for end devices that support port-channeling.  For double-sided you of course need the downstream devices to also support vPC, such as a core layer of Nexus 9k connecting to a pair of Nexus 5k.